Sql create statement
How would you quickly create a replica of a SQL table in Oracle without copying its data? The idea is to quickly duplicate a table with many columns and numerous records without moving all those records. The new table could be used to temporarily hold data during processing and truncated after processing
CREATE TABLE <table_name> AS
SELECT *
FROM <original_table_name>
WHERE 1 = 2;
